# Colour residuals according to factors in R

Tags: r

I have a linear model for which I plot the residuals using the function `plot(model.lm$residuals)`. However, my dataset is comprised of two big groups of observations (Territories), and I would like to identify the residuals by group. A binary variable within my dataset already identifies the two groups apart by giving a "1" to one group and a "0" to the other. How could I get R to plot my residuals and give different colours to the residuals associated with my 1's and my 0's?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data(iris)
iris$isVersicolor <- factor(as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor"))

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = iris)
plot(residuals(fit), col = iris$isVersicolor)
```

[image]