# Colour code different residual groups on the same plot R

Tags: r, plot, colors, linear-regression

From this example: [Colour residuals according to factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263354/colour-residuals-according-to-factors-in-r)

How would you do this if you had more than just two groups? Eg. What if I had 5 groups in my residual plot and I wanted to colour code each of them?

Comment: Instead of `factor(as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor"))`, set the color for example: `as.numeric(factor(iris$Species))`. This will color by the number of groups in `iris$Species`.

Comment: This worked perfect. Sorry I can't upvote the comment!

Comment: Great! I posted it as an answer so you can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provided, change

```
factor(as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor")),
```

to

```
as.numeric(factor(iris$Species)).
```

This will color by the number of groups in `iris$Species`